# trying to make a foreign key but MySql won't allow me, is there any way?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have these 3 tables

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `enrollment` (
  `STUDENT_NUM` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `SUBJECT_NUM` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `UNITS` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `DAYS` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `TIME_START` time NOT NULL,
  `TIME_END` time NOT NULL,
  `ROOM_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `PRELIM` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MIDTERM` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FINALS` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FINAL_GRADE` float(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEMESTER` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SCHOOL_YEAR` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `DATE_ADDED` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`STUDENT_NUM`,`SUBJECT_NUM`),
  KEY `SUBJECT_NUM` (`SUBJECT_NUM`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `subjects` (
  `SUBJECT_NUM` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `EMPLOYEE_NUM` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `SUBJECT_TITLE` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEPARTMENT` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UNITS` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `DAYS` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `TIME_START` time NOT NULL,
  `TIME_END` time NOT NULL,
  `room_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SEMESTER` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `SCHOOL_YEAR` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `COUNT` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STATUS` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLAG` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `DATE_ADDED` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SUBJECT_NUM`),
  UNIQUE KEY `SUBJECT_NUM` (`SUBJECT_NUM`),
  KEY `EMPLOYEE_NUM` (`EMPLOYEE_NUM`),
  KEY `EMPLOYEE_NUM_2` (`EMPLOYEE_NUM`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `room` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `room` (`room`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;
```

what i am trying to do is make the field ROOM_ID from enrollment and subjects foreign key and the reference be the ID from room.. the ROOM_ID must not be unique...

i am getting this error

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`enrollmentdb`.`#sql-277_164`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-277_164_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`ROOM_ID`) REFERENCES `room` (`ID`))
```

when i am using this SQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE enrollment
ADD FOREIGN KEY (room_id)
REFERENCES room(ID)
```

Comment: this won't solve your problem, but change charset to utf8 instead of latin1. It will save a lot of headaches along the road.

Comment: And `COLLATE=UTF8_GENERAL_CI` is also a good idea

Comment: There may be a problem of sequence of statements.

first create table room then other one

Comment: the enrollment and subjects tables are already in my database with data. i've just added the table room and the field ROOM_ID in those 2 tables above.. i just wanted to create a relationship between those tables through the ROOM_ID but i need ROOM_ID to not be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code if its working :

```
ALTER TABLE enrollment
 ADD CONSTRAINT ROOM_ID_fk
 FOREIGN KEY(ROOM_ID)
 REFERENCES room(ID);
```

Thanks!

Comment: im getting this error:

#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`enrollmentdb`.`#sql-277_16e`, CONSTRAINT `ROOM_ID_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`ROOM_ID`) REFERENCES `room` (`ID`))

Comment: I have just tried with your table even, and its working fine.

Comment: Do you have data exist in enrollment and room table?

Comment: yes i have data existing in enrollment and room table... i can't delete the data on the enrollment but i can on room.. i'll try deleting the data on room..

Comment: i've deleted all the data on the room table.. still getting the same error

Comment: just do one thing, for a while take your enrollment table backup and then remove all data from it, then try all these process in sequence. it may have working.

Answer (score 0):

`room_id` is capitalised in your table. Try:

```
ALTER TABLE enrollment
ADD FOREIGN KEY (ROOM_ID)
REFERENCES room(ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

**replace 'room_id' with 'ROOM_ID'**